# Inverse function theorem as consequence of Implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm using Rudin, and in its proof of the implicit function theorem, it uses the inverse function theorem. I've heard that you can prove the inverse function theorem as a consequence of the implicit function theorem, but I can't figure out how to do this. Does anyone have some ideas how to start?

Comment: Do you want the version in Banach spaces?

Comment: I'm working in Rn